# Codeigniter: call a function in View From Controller

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I am New to Codeigniter. In my Sample Application I add a new Tab called "RegForm" in my Main.php(View Folder).  When i Click the RegForm Tab it load the New Window(width='800px' height='500px'). i understand the concept but i dont know how to write coding in Codeigniter.
Basicall i call a function in Controller file when i Clicked the RegForm tab. and i need to call a function in View where i load a window with properties. amm i correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu could do this (if I understood correctly):

View 'someview' contains this link:

```
$atts = array(
              'width'      => '800',
              'height'     => '500',
              'scrollbars' => 'yes',
              'status'     => 'yes',
              'resizable'  => 'yes',
            );
echo anchor_popup('mycontroller/mymethod','Click this for a popup',$atts);
```

(anchor_popup is a funcion in the URL helper, just autoload it, it's really useful)

in Controller 'mycontroller':

```
class Mycontroller extends CI_Controller {

    //function index()
    // other functions

    function mymethod() 
    {
      $this->load->model('mymodelforthis');
      $data['properties'] = $this->mymodelforthis->get_properties();
      $this->load->view('myview',$data);
    }
}
```

THen, in 'myview', you display `$properties` the way you want
Hope this helps, lmk

Comment: Hi Damien ,  Really Thanks to Reply it got working Greatly. but one thing how to ignore the window shows "Click this for a popup". instead directly load the view. is there any way?

Comment: Well, if you want a new page and not a popup, just dont' use the popup ;) Do you mean 'Click this for a popup' shows as page title?

Comment: @Damn i need popup window but the window doesn't load the view. it displays href "click this for a popup". i need to load the view in pop up window.

Comment: I believe you're implementing something wrong, because it works the way I showed you..are you calling the right controller and views? (like in the example I posted)

Comment: ya i made a small mistake. Thanks for co operating @Damien Pirsy

Comment: what if i need to have an image inside a anchor tag like <a href="#"><img src="something"/></a>